# pause script if next row is empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, selenium-chromedriver

I have this code that runs in a loop:

```
while True:   #repeats script in infinity 


    df = pd.read_csv('screenshot.csv', header = 0, usecols= ['url','guid'])

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        r = driver.get(row['url'])
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") # takes a screen shot within a range of 2 seconds for each page and names it with the DT when the screenshot was taken 

        for n in range(2):
            file_name = str(row['guid'])
            driver.save_screenshot(file_name+ '.png') #saves screenshot with guid number
            it = iter(file_name) #iterated through file_name and skips duplicated ones
            for i in it:
                if i == file_name:       #avoids duplicated file names
                     continue
   df['url']    
   for i, row in df.iterrows() :        #if url row url is empty will sleep for 10 minutes
       if row['url'] == '':
           time.sleep(10)

           print('guid is' + str(file_name))



print(file_name)  #prints the name file name
driver.quit()
```

My question concerns this part:

```
df['url']    
   for i, row in df.iterrows() :        #if url row url is empty will sleep for 10 minutes
       if row['url'] == '':
           time.sleep(10)
```

I need the while loop to pause if next row in column url is empty.
The script keep running over and over without applying the sleeping time when the next row is empty. Can you please help me?

Comment: what do you mean with "pause script"? If you want to end the script execution, simply use the system function  sys.exit() ...

Comment: @J.Doe, please clarify what you mean by "I need the while loop to pause if next row in column url is empty"

Comment: @ Loss of human identity the original file which is "screenshot.csv" will contain scraped url from an API, so i need the script to pause if the api doesn't bring any urls because in this case the following row in url column will be empty

Comment: @ Loss of human identity I also updated my question

Comment: @J.Doe sorry, you are still not explaining what does "pause script" mean... you are not running a debugger...

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear enough- I am still new with python- I need selenium to pause taking screenshots OR I need it to keep running until value of next row becomes available. But what it is doing currently is opening a new driver and taking screenshots from the beginning of the sheet again